# Правильная привязка данных и чтение из DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Здравствуйте, решил узнать о грамотном размещении и чтении в и из datagrid в впф. Столкнулся с очень сложной ситуацией и решил ее очень, на мой взгляд плохим образом.

1) у меня есть подключенная база данных, все названия полей на англ. языке, а в представлении на datagrid нужно, что бы имена полей были на русском.

2) я решил использовать `var`, например `var a = from b in db.clients select new { Имя = b.Name };`

3) тут сразу вспомнил, что особо я с var не повеселюсь, поэтому сделал метод который сделает строку из п. 2 и установит `datagrid.itemssource = a`;

4) ну и при чтении я столкнулся с еще большей проблемой... Не могу прочитать выделеную строку в класс `datagridrow`, он пытается привестись к анонимному типу... Но если я делаю переменную `var`, то и получаю на выходе `object`.

5) в итоге я использую вот что... `dynamic changerow = dataGrid.SelectedValue;` во время выполнения ошибок не вызывается, но на мой взгляд это ужасно.
Прошу вас помочь мне понять как мне грамотно привязывать данные, что бы я мог без особых проблем читать и записывать данные в `datagrid`, если это возможно без привязки в `xml`. Спасибо!

Comment: Создайте класс, создавайте вместо анонимных классов - известный вам тип классов и в селектед будет он же.

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо. Думаю дальше, только если привязываться через xml, более выгодного пути больше не вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.DataGrid. Все можно сделать гораздо проще. Правда, придется описывать каждый столбец в ручную.
В принципе можно делать привязку, как Вы и сделали в пункте 3 datagrid.ItemSource = a; Правильнее все таки будет сделать в коде XAML. a - должно быть public. Тип столбца может быть и другим . [Эта](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html) страница Вам в помощь.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemSource = {Binding a} 
 SelectedItem ={Binding selectedItem}>
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Ваш текст сюда"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" HeaderStyle=""></DataGridTextColumn>
```

2. Правильная привязка данных. Советую Вам поинтересоваться, что такое ORM, на пример EF, и что такое MVVM подход и как работает все в связке

Comment: Да, я в курсе про ОРМ и EF, тут была чуть чуть другая задача, которая не требовала создания целой БД. спасибо